# Submit a function that forks inside ThreadPoolExecutor in python?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, fork

I need to use python `AsyncIO` with a `ProcessPoolExecutor` inside a class method but I cannot due to pickle errors (cannot pickle a function or the same class' method). I tried to use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and submit a function `foo` that forks with `os.fork()` immediately (to avoid GIL). The `ThreadPoolExecutor` would be initialised in class' `__init__` method. After fork() the parent only waits for the child to exit (thus performing I/O) while the child performs some CPU intensive task. After measuring the latency by calling this method many times from different threads, it seems like the different invocations of `foo` are executed (almost) sequentially..why is that ?

Here is my class

```
class Foo():
   def __init__(self):
       self._tp = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()

   def.test(self):
      child=os.fork()
      if(child==0):
        os._exit(os.EX_OK)
      else:
        os.waitpid(child, 0)
        return "ok"

   async def __call__(self, request: starlette.requests.Request):
       json_request = await request.json()
       res = await asyncio.wrap_future(self._tp.submit(self.test)
       return res
```

Comment: Please, provide a minimal reproducible example of what you have, and how you are measuring it. There is not a chance anyone will try to follow this amount of vaguely desdribed complex steps to provide you an answer.

Comment: I am more interested in the concept of why submitting a function in a threadpoolexecutor and forking inside, is a good idea or not.

Comment: Please add some sleeps, time measurements and repeatable code. I don't see many reasons why forking would be a bad idea, but do note that you may end up creating more threads than you meant (first process forks, then you have both parent and child having the other threads attempting to submit once more). It's a bit challenging to think about all the implications.

Comment: @Bharel thank you for the comment. I thought that when the parent process forks then the child process only has one thread. But is this thread subject to the thread pool of the parent process, to compete for the GIL? If I have two processes, don't I have two GILs as well? What am I missing?

Comment: You seem to be right, I have no clue what happens in that case then. Don't know how Python manages forks within threads, and if it sets the locks / state correctly. Either way, it just sounds like a problematic design for a program.